# CUDA doesn't work!

Tags: cuda, gpu, blender

I have Kubuntu 22.04 and I intalled all drivers via command line using
'' sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
I'm unable to run Davinci Resolve with CUDA. I get an error message, "The GPU failed to perform image processing because of an error."
I have GS66 with a 2070 SUPER GPU